# Perform operation after all the call back functions got executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, callback

I have the following scenerio

> asyncFunction(x1) 
>   asyncFunction(x2) 
>   asyncFunction(x3) 
>   ...
>   ...
>   asyncFunction(xn)

The function of the asyncFunction is to get data and image from the server and append to the body of the html. The problem is the data sizes vary each time so each function may complete at different time. This makes it useless as some top elements would be still loading even after the bottom elements are loaded.

How can I write the Javascript code in such a way that the functions data is appended after all the callbacks have been completed or alternatively execute the function i only after function j has been executed, where j < i.

I am using Javascript and Ajax for getting the data. 
PS: This is almost similar to a news feed.

Comment: [jQuery.when()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/)

Comment: Since `asyncFunction` is asynchronous, there is no way to know when it will finish, unless `asyncFunction` itself provides a mechanism, like a callback, where you can specify a method to be called, or some code to be executed, when it is done.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jquery deffered objects](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/)

In every function define `deffered` object, for example:

```
var asyncFunction1 = function(x1) {
   var d = new $.Deferred();
   ...
   //when it will be ready
   d.resolve();
   ...
   return d.promise();
}
```

And then

```
$.when(asyncFunction1(), asyncFunction2(), ...).done(function() {
    // here all functions will be finished
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use can do this easily with using promises. Inform yourself about the topic with articles like [this](https://functionwhatwhat.com/introduction-to-promises-in-javascript/). Then I would suggest you have a look at the [Q framework](https://github.com/kriskowal/q).

What you are looking for would then be that you want to execute code only after all promises have been resolved. This would look like this if you use Q:

```
Q.all([a,b,c,d]).then(function(){
     //runs after all of the promises fulfilled
});
```